# "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error in Java (read data from files to array)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I completed this project, but there seems to be a problem with the "readLines" method and the integer array that I was using:

```
package careers;
import java.util.*;

/**
*
* @author hna
*/
public class Careers 
{
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String[] career = new String[20];
    int[] salary = new int[20];
    int count;

    count = readLines(career, salary);
    sortInfo(career, salary, count);
    printTable(career, salary, count);
}

/*****************************************************************************/

public static int readLines(String[] career, int[] salary) throws Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    java.io.File careers = new java.io.File("Careers.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(careers);

    while(infile.hasNextLine())
    {
        career[i] = infile.nextLine();
        infile.nextLine();
        salary[i] = infile.nextInt();
        i++;
        count++;
    }

    infile.close();
    return count;
} // end readLines

/*****************************************************************************/

public static void sortInfo(String[] career, int[] salary, int count)
{
    boolean swapped;
    int i;
    String tempCareer;
    int tempSalary;

    do
    {
        swapped = false;

        for(i = 0; (i < count - 1); i++)
        {
            if(salary[i] < salary[i + 1])
            {
                tempSalary = salary[i];
                salary[i] = salary[i + 1];
                salary[i + 1] = tempSalary;

                tempCareer = career[i];
                career[i] = career[i + 1];
                career[i + 1] = tempCareer;
                swapped = true;
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } while(swapped);
} // end sortInfo

/*****************************************************************************/

public static void printTable(String[] career, int[] salary, int count)
{
    int i;

    System.out.printf("%-10s%56s%n", "Job Titles", "Salary");

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        System.out.printf("%-60s%-,30d%n", career[i], salary[i]);

} // end printTable
```

}

Somehow, changing from "career[i] = infile.nextLine()" to "career[i] = infile.next()" makes it accept the integer inputs and works, but it only read the first string of my input. i.e:"Computer" instead of reading the whole line "Computer and Information Research. But if I leave it as " career[i] = infile.nextLine()", there will be some problem with reading the integers from the file.
This is the input file:

```
 Computer and Information Research Scientists
 102190
 Computer and Information Analysts
 80460
 Computer Systems Analysts
 79680
 Information Security Analysts
 86170
 Software Developers and Programmers
 87100
 Computer Programmers
 74280
 Software Developers, Applications
 90060
 Software Developers, Systems Software
 99000
 Web Developers
 62500
 Database and Systems Administrators and Network Architects
 76880
 Database Administrators
 77080
 Network and Computer Systems Administrators
 72560
 Computer Network Architects
 91000
 Computer Support Specialists
 48900
 Computer User Support Specialists
 46420
 Computer Network Support Specialists
 59090
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: check for `infile.hasNextInt()` before `salary[i] = infile.nextInt();`

Comment: Can you put the stack trace. Moreover, can you write what you want the application to do ?

Comment: I'm assuming your input file is separated by newlines, if that is the case you will want to always read `infile.nextLine()` to consume the entire line and then use `Integer.parseInt()` to use the integer.

Comment: Thanks guys. The application reads data from the file "Careers.txt", then create and sort a pair of parallel arrays in terms of highest salary. Then print out  a table with those sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read two lines in each loop. If you can change the structure of the file content to *one line for each record*, it should be much simpler.

Anyway, this might be not the best solution for above case, but it will work:

```
public static int readLines(String[] career, int[] salary) throws Exception{

    int i = 0, j=0, count = 0;
    java.io.File careers = new java.io.File("Careers.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(careers);
    String line="";
    while(infile.hasNextLine()){    

        line=infile.nextLine(); 

        //check if you are reading the string's line or number's line
        if(line.trim().replaceAll("\\d","").length()!=0){ 
            career[j] = line;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            salary[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
            i++;
            count++;
        }   
    }
    infile.close();
    return count;
}
```

Depends on your `.txt file` content, you might need to handle some exception